# Why is my Laravel+OneAuth Twitter login failing?

Tags: routes, twitter-oauth, laravel

I'm wrapping my head around Laravel and the Oneauth bundle for logging in via twitter.

I've been following the tutorials by Michael Calkin: http://youtu.be/xlUFiZhwFiE

- I've installed OneAuth via artisan
- run the migration
- created my twitter app
- created a User table with id, social_uid, social_provider, username, email
- created a controller connect.php: `class Connect_Controller extends OneAuth\Auth\Controller {}`
- routed to connect: `Route::controller( 'connect' );`
- copied out the functions (below) in the video, which make a sort of sense to me
- cleared my browser cache

So, in testing:

- I've visited the link `mysite.dev/connect/session/twitter`
- clicked the button caused twitter to request auth (created a new account for testing)
- authorised twitter
- was returned to `users/social_register`
- a new user was added to the table `oneauth_client`
- the snippet below should just display the returned user data, but what actually happens is that although the URL reads /users/social_register, the view users.index is displayed!

controller: users.php

```
...
public function get_social_register()
{
    $user_data = Session::get( 'oneauth' );

    dd( $user_data );
}
```

(the full code is here: https://gist.github.com/ptim/a29bb86b3fb7455c19ba )

ah, and my routes:

```
Route::controller( 'connect' );
Route::get('users/(:any)', 'users@index' );
Route::controller(Controller::detect());
```

some redundancy there... not sure if that matters

Any suggestions appreciated! Tx, Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are redirecting users/(:all) query to index function of the users controller with this:

```
Route::get('users/(:any)', 'users@index' );
```

Try this instead of up:

```
Route::any('users/(:any?)', array('uses' => 'users@(:1)', 'defaults'=>'index'));
```

Comment: fantastic! tx, routing is still a dark art for me!